# How can I join two tables and get a count of the number of times the joins match if there might not be a corresponding entry in one table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite I have two tables:

```
public class DeckSource {
   [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
   public string DeckGuid      { get; set; }
   public string Type        { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Deck {
   [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
   public long IdEs { get; set; }
   public string DeckGuid      { get; set; }
   public string Type        { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My application has an add button which when pressed takes the data from a row in DeckSource and populates Deck.  So for every DeckSource there can be multiple decks. I would like to get a report from DeckSource that shows how many times each Deck has been added to Deck.

If the DeckSource table looks like this:

```
DeckGuid   Name
abc        abcrow
def        deform
ghi        ghirow
```

and    Deck looks like this:

```
IdEs    DeckGuid    Name
1       abc         abcrow
2       abc         abcrow
3       abc         abcrow
4       chi         ghirow
```

How can I create a report that shows:

```
DeckGuid   Name     Qty
abc        abcrow   3
def        defrow   0
ghi        ghirow   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
select decksource.deckguid,decksource.name,count(*)
from decksource 
left join deck 
on decksource.deckguid = deck.deckguid
group by decksource.deckguid
```